# Promises in Ionic 2 / Angular 2, how to?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise, ionic2

I have two functions:

```
this.geQuizStorage();
this.getQuizData();

geQuizStorage() {
    this.quizStorage.getAnswers().then(data => {
        return data;
    });
}

getQuizData() {
    this.quizData.getQuiz().then(data => {
        return data;
    });
}
```

I am trying use promises for the 2 functions and wait until both are done, something like:

```
http.when(this.geQuizStorage(), this.getQuizData()).when(data => {
    // data[0] first function response
    // data[1]
})
```

any ideas how to do this in Ionic 2 / Angular 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with ES6 promise's [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function. No need for external libraries.

```
Promise.all([this.geQuizStorage(), this.getQuizData()]).then(data => {
  //do stuff with data[0], data[1]
});
```

Your functions should return promises in order for this to work, so I suggest the following modification:

```
geQuizStorage() {
    return this.quizStorage.getAnswers().then(data => {
        return data;
    });
}

getQuizData() {
    return this.quizData.getQuiz().then(data => {
        return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to resolve some promise and return it inside my 2 functions?

Comment: I missed the part where your functions don't return promises... but all you need is to make `getQuizStorage` and `getQuizData` return promises. This can be easily accomplished by adding `return` before calling the service function. See edited answer.

Comment: Can you make them return data?

Comment: i'm doing this, but i have an issue that if the request fails, promise.all enter the rejection function but with an error : 
Uncaught (in promise) 
i'm opening the issue here can you help me :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460438/promise-all-not-access-in-rejection-function?noredirect=1#comment75922854_44460438

Answer (score 3):

Basically you don't need to create another wrapper function for your service call, just to return a data(unless you have your validation logic out there to validate data). Then pass those two function in [**`Observable.forkJoin`**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) by passing method `promises/observable's` & `subscribe` over that observable to wait till those get complete.

```
 Observable.forkJoin([this.getQuizData(),this.geQuizStorage()])
  .subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data[0], data[1]);
     //both call succeeded
});
```